# <input type="file"> issue in IOS 9 and IOS 8 in UIWebview

Tags: html, file-io, uiwebview, ios8, ios9

Im a web developer and New to the IPhone programming.
I have Small problem related to the `<input type="file">`

Now i have created a website that inside it there's post ad, and i convert this website to IPHONE using UIWebview in Xcode 5.

Now the whole application is pretty good...just when user click on `<input type="file">` in IOS 9 or IOS 8....it's only showing a cancel button, no select photo button or take photo button , then the app hang or lag.

I searched a lot for this, but no good solution till now.

This is my Code:

**file.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
@interface TESTWebViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator; 
@end
```

**file.m**

```
#import "TESTWebViewController.h"
@interface TESTWebViewController ()

@end

@implementation TESTWebViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{ self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad { 
 _webView.delegate = self;
[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
NSURL *App = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website.com/"];
NSURLRequest *Request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:APP ];
[_webView loadRequest:Request ];


}


-(void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)    
(void))completion

{
if ( self.presentedViewController)
{
    [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
}
}

-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
self.activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
self.activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Thank you very much..